# When to add a dependency? Are there cases where I should rather copy the functionality?

Tags: node.js

I lately helped out on a project, where I added a really small dependency - in fact, it only contained a regular expression (https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-unc-path).

The feedback I got from the developer of the project was that he tries to minimize third-party dependencies if they can be implemented easily - whereby he - if I understand it correctly - asks me to just copy the code instead of adding another dependency.

To me, adding a new dependency looks just like putting some lines of code into an extra file in the repo. In addition, the developers will get informed by an update if the code needs a change.

Is it just a religious thought that drives a developer to do this? Are there maybe any costs (performance- or space-wise, etc) when adding a dependency?

Comment: copying is just wrong. if its not your code, don't pass it as your code. depending on license you could run into legal trouble for copying.

Answer (score 1):

I also had some disputes with my managers once concerning the third party libraries, the problem was even greater he got into believing that you should version the `node_modules` folder.

> The source of any conflict usually is the ignorance.

**His arguments were:**

- you should deliver to the client a working product not needing for him to do any other jobs like npm install
- if `github`, `npm` is down in the moment when you run `npm install` on the server what you will do ?
- if the library that you install has a bug who will be responsible

**My arguments were:**

- versioning `node_modules` is not going to work due to how package dependencies work, each library will download his own `node_modules` dependencies and then your git repository will grow rapidly to hundreds of mb. Deploy will become more and more slow, downloading each time half a gb of code take time. NPM does use a module caching mechanism if there are no changes it will not download code uselessly.
- the problem with [`left-pad`](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/) was painfull but after that `npm` implemented a locking system and now for each package you just lock to a specific commit hash.
- And Github, and npm does not have just a single instance service, they run in cloud.
- When installing a dependency you always have some ideas behind and there are community best practices, usually they resume to: *1. Does the repo has unit tests*. *2. The download number* *3. When was the latest update*.
- Node.js ecosystem is built on modularity, it is not that node is so popular cause of some luck, but cause of how it was designed to create modules and reuse them. Sometimes working in node.js environment feels like putting lego pieces together and building your toy. This is the main cause of super fast development in node.js. People just reuse stuff.

Finally he stayed on his own ideas, and I left the project :D.

Comment: Sounds like a gravestone bearing the inscription: He was right, he insisted on his right and he was proven to be right after all.